# Creating a java program which getting SQLite data and Insert in Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle

I've just started my adventure with programming in SQL using JAVA.
I have Linux and Oracle Database on VirtualBox Machine.

My project is about situation, when a client give me a SQLite3 Database and I have to convert it to Oracle Database.

I've read some code but it gives error
Code:

> CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Move" AS

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
public class getting {

        public static void doIt() throws Exception{
            Connection conn;
            ResultSet rs;
            Statement stat;
            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://127.0.0.1/media/sf_SHARE/baza.db");
            } catch (SQLException e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            try{
                 stat = conn.createStatement();

            try{
                rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * from entities");
                    while(rs.next()){
                        String w1= rs.getString("ID");
                        String w2 = rs.getString("TEXT");
                        System.out.println(w1+w2);
                    }
            }finally{}
        }finally{}
            {try {rs.close();
            }catch (Exception ignore){}
            try {conn.close();
            }catch (Exception ignore){}
            try {stat.close();
            }catch (Exception ignore){}
}
}
}
/



create or replace function Move return varchar2 as
language java name 'getting.doIt() return java.language.String';
/





select Move from dual;
```

I've got a error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/sqlite/JDBC

Is connection in `DriverManager.getConnection()` is good?
Any ideas what I did wrong?

Cheers
najdzion

Comment: Put the SQLite driver jar in your classpath

Answer (score 1):

You have to download JDBC driver from here: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads and import downloaded JAR to your project. 
Also, as good practice, don't store connections as hard-coded strings.
If you are using maven, check your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Add your jar co Classpath:

```
> javac Example.java
> java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-(VERSION).jar" Example   # in Windows
or 
> java -classpath ".:sqlite-jdbc-(VERSION).jar" Example   # in Mac or Linux
```

or you can do it via your IDE.

Comment: JAR - imported and nothing have changed

Any other ideas?

Comment: @najdzion15: Yep.  Hire a professional Java developer to tutor you.